# Is dual monitor power consumption high?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I got a new Samsung TV (forget model) for Christmas, and it was my intention to buy another one of the same kind so I could finally experience a dual monitor (TV) setup at home.

However, I am kind of concerned that having dual monitors drain too much unnecessary power. I'm not really worried about the bill, but it's more an environmental concern.

I would just like to know if my concerns are valid or if new technologies (like LCD, which my monitors use, etc.) are able to consume less power than traditionally and therefore I wouldn't need to worry about it too much.

Comment: Environmental concerns? Haha, the *manufacture* of your second TV will likely cause more environmental damage overall than you'll ever recoup by saving electricity. If you're really concerned about environmental impact, *don't buy a second TV*.

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple.  2 monitors of same make/model uses twice the power of one.  Compared to older tech like CRT, they use less power but since you have the new TVs it is a moot point.  The specifications for the monitor will likely provide power consumption when on or sleeping so you can decide the environmental impact of your hardware.

Comment: The power consumption of your device(s) are printed on the back - unless you live in a country, which I cannot tell from four profile, where this is not already a law.

I bought several 32-inch TV just for the same purpose. My roommate falls asleep with TV programs and awakes to TV programs, it matters little what program on what channel. I fall and rise with with hair-guitar, and my roommate falls and rises with Judge Judy. Even the cat in my household falls and rises with some channel.

I pay the bills every month and I see no difference. Low power TV, high-priced channels?! Take your pick!

Answer (score 1):

In general,if you got a new LED,LCD power consumption is not that great, especially if you turn them off your not using them like the 8 hours you probably sleep and the 8 hours you probably work.  If you want to know how much power they use get a **kill-o-watt** power meter for exact numbers or read the manual for typical drawn.